# Last inserted _key in ArangoDB with AQL?

Tags: lastinsertid, arangodb, aql

How can i receive a last inserted _key in ArangoDB with AQL query?
I put the item in the collection, the following element must contain _key created element. How do I get this _key?

Comment: Are you referring to an AQL INSERT query that should return the generated key(s)? Or to an AQL select query that is executed after a previous insert operation (in a separate query or operation) has taken place?

Comment: @k.djonua: Do you still need help with this problem?

Comment: @13abylon, no, thanks. I'm resolve this trouble with other method.

Comment: @k.djonua Could you write an answer how you solved the problem for future reference.

Answer (score 9):

Update on this question:
Since ArangoDB 2.4 it is possible to retrieve the just-inserted document (or documents) even with an AQL query.

With previous versions of ArangoDB 2.3, the syntax for a single document INSERT was:

```
INSERT { value: 1 } IN collection
```

with no way to retrieve the system attributes (`_key`, `_rev` etc.) for the just-inserted document. Since 2.4, the following is possible, too:

```
INSERT { value: 1 } IN collection LET result = NEW RETURN result
```

The above returns the created document, including the specified attributes (`value` in the above case) and the system attributes.

It also works for multi-document inserts, e.g. the following query

```
FOR i IN 1..10 
  INSERT { value: i } IN collection
```

can be turned into

```
FOR i IN 1..10 
  INSERT { value: i } IN collection LET result = NEW RETURN result
```

to return all inserted documents.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly it is not possible at the moment (2.3) to receive the last inserted `_key` with an AQL query.

However you can use `db.<collection>.save({ Hello : "World" }):` to retrieve the latest `_key`

Comment: To clarify: db.<collection>.save returns a document which has the `_key` attribute.

Comment: Since 2.4 now it is possible. So if you are using at least ArangoDB 2.4 ignore my answer and look to stj's answer

Answer (score 0):

return document

`INSERT { myValue: "123", myValue2: "456" } INTO myCollection RETURN NEW`

return _key only

`INSERT { myValue: "123", myValue2: "456" } INTO myCollection LET inserted = NEW RETURN inserted._key`